# Jquery plugin move an element from one to another

Tags: jquery

I am fairly new to Jquery and am using a plugin to move one element from to another.
It is here -
https://github.com/EmilStenstrom/jQuery-animate_from_to/blob/master/example_usage.html

The plugin does the first half of the manipulation.
I am trying to have the image permanently attach to the another box while also staying in the original location as well.

I've tried this - but it doesn't work. Am I in the right direction?

```
$("#button1").on('click', function(event){
$('#cart').attr('src', '$(this).attr('src');'});
});
```

Comment: A button with attribute src?

Answer (score 2):

You have quotes and a `}` that you shouldn't have. Use

```
$('#cart').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
```

or better :

```
$('#cart').attr('src', this.src);
```

Note that instead of giving a `src` attribute to elements which shouldn't have one, if you do this to store a variable, you'd better use a data attribute :

```
<a id=button1 data-src="...">button</a>

...

$('#cart').attr('src', $(this).data('src'));
```

Answer (score 0):

When your animation is do the following :

```
/* detach #cart */
myCart = $('#cart').remove();

/* add #cart to #container */
$('#container').append(myCart);
```